# GridView - handle select link

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP.NET 4 and MVC and trying to add code to handle the "select" link.  Once the user selects the row, I need to go display a new page with more detail.  I have tried to capture the rowcommand but I never hit a the breakpoint.  This is my current GridView code for the first page -

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<ValidationPortal.Models.Contact>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <p>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
                    SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
                    SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Contacts]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    </p>
    </form>

</asp:Content>
```

What do I need to add to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to specify an [OnSelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onselectedindexchanged.aspx) event in your grid markup. Your event would probably just redirect to your details page with the ID of the selected item. It would look something like this:

Grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectEvent">
        // rest of grid definitions
</asp:GridView>
```

C#:

```
protected void SelectEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GridView1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
       Response.Redirect("yourpage.aspx?itemid=" + (int)GridView1.SelectedValue);
}
```

Personally, for what you are doing I would skip the select command and create an item template with a link to your url, as shown [here](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/04/linkbutton-gridview-querystring.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
           // Do something
         }
     }
```

If you dont want to using the row command or you want to fire the rowcommand explicitly then use this following segment of code

```
int GridView1TotalCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
        int r = Convert.ToInt32(dslno)-1;
        if (r != -1)
        {
            if (GridView1TotalCount > r)
            {

                GridViewRow thisGridView1 = GridView1.Rows[r];
                ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + thisGvEmpMaster.RowIndex);
               // Do something here you have datakey like
           int dkkey = Convert.ToString(GridView1.DataKeys[thisGridView1.RowIndex].Value);


            }
         }
```